# ASP.NET Core 1 RC2 - database schema

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-1.0

Can somebody advise how to get the schema in ASP.NET Core 1 RC2?

```
using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=.;Database=Mydb;Trusted_Connection=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=true"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            connection.GetSchema("Tables"); // doesn't work

        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `connection.GetSchema` has been depreciated in Asp.Net Core due as it returns the `DataTable` which has also been depreciated.  The way to do this now is is to open run the `ExecuteReader()` function, and then use the `GetSchemaColumn()` function from the resulting reader object.

Here is a sample:

```
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection("Server=(localdb)\\v11.0;Database=MyAdventureWorks;Trusted_Connection=True"))
            {

                connection.Open();

                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from [Person].[Person]", connection);
                DbDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader(System.Data.CommandBehavior.SchemaOnly);

                if (reader.CanGetColumnSchema())
                {
                    var columns = reader.GetColumnSchema();
                    foreach (var column in columns)
                    {
                        Console.Write("ColumName: " + column.ColumnName);
                        Console.Write(", DataTypeName: " + column.DataTypeName);
                        Console.Write(", ColumnSize: " + column.ColumnSize);
                        Console.WriteLine(", IsUnique: " + column.IsUnique);
                    }
                }
                else
                    throw new Exception("Connection does not support GetColumnSchema.");
            }

            Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Note: I think this is still be stabalized in Rc2.  For example the column.IsKey function always returning null.

Comment: Fiddling with .net core 1.1. I can still see Reader.GetSchemaTable(), and I can't see Reader.GetColumnSchema(). Wonder what the story is?

Comment: Hi there.  I just created a new console app, targeting .netcoreapp 1.1, add System.Data.SqlClient 4.3, and pasted the code, and it still works.  So I'm unsure why you can not see the GetSchemaTable().

Comment: Yup I can see it, but GetSchemaTable() returns a [DataTable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/api/system.data.datatable) that has no properties or methods?

Answer (score 0):

If you need all table names from a database I managed to do this:

```
public List<string> getTables()
{
    List<string> result = new List<string>();
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(appSettings.ConnectionStringSamples))
    {
        connection.Open();
        using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("SELECT name FROM sys.Tables;", connection))
        using (SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader())
        while (reader.Read()) result.Add(reader["name"].ToString());
    }

    return result;
}
```